# Cannot Get Windows MR Controllers Unity Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-mixed-reality

I tried using the following code from the official Windows documentation but I couldn't get the inputs from the controller.

if (Input.GetButton("Button 14 "))
{
  // ...
}

How can I get the inputs from the Mixed Reality controllers?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/gestures_and_motion_controllers_in_unity details that to get a key but its qualified name you use

```
if (Input.GetKey("name")) { ... }
```

> For button14 you would use "joystick button 14".
>
> Else try "button 14" since the documentation isn't clear which one will work.

I just googled and had a little research since I don't personally own this set of hardware to test, so I hope it works (otherwise I'll delete answer).